# Need to subset the main dataframe using the column information on another file

Tags: r

Please help I have the main dataset which I want to subset by column and the column information in on another file. In the present case, I want to create 3 dataframe from the main file with the required column are in the ColData (c(XX,CE.02), c(YY,CE.03,CE.01), c(ZZ,CE.05)).

```
XX <- c(1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0)
YY <- c(0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0)
ZZ <- c(1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1)
AL.01 <- c(NA,0,0,NA,NA,0,NA,0,0,3,0,0,0,3,0,0)
AL.02 <- c(NA,0,0,NA,NA,0,NA,0,0,4,0,0,0,2,0,0)
AL.03 <- c(NA,0,0,NA,NA,0,NA,0,0,3,0,0,0,3,0,0)
CE.01 <- c(NA,0,0,NA,NA,0,NA,0,0,3,0,0,0,3,0,0)
CE.02 <- c(NA,0,0,NA,NA,0,NA,0,0,3,0,0,0,2,0,0)
CE.03 <- c(NA,0,0,NA,NA,0,NA,0,0,3,0,0,0,2,0,0)
CE.04 <- c(NA,0,0,NA,NA,0,NA,0,0,3,0,0,0,1,0,0)
CE.05 <- c(NA,0,0,NA,NA,0,NA,0,0,3,0,0,0,1,0,0)

RCAQA <- c('XX','YY','ZZ')
QuestionID1 <- c('CE.02','CE.03','CE.05')
QuestionID2 <- c('','CE.01','')

MainData <- data.frame(XX,YY,ZZ,AL.01,AL.02,AL.03,CE.01,CE.02,CE.03,CE.04,CE.05)

ColData <- data.frame(RCAQA,QuestionID1,QuestionID2)
```

MainData

[image: MainData]

ColData

[image: ColData]

Required Output Dataframe 1 c(XX,CE.02)

[image: RequiredOutputDataframe1]

Required Output Dataframe 2 c(YY,CE.03,CE.01)

[image: RequiredOutputDataframe2]

Required Output Dataframe 3  c(ZZ,CE.05)

[image: RequiredOutputDataframe3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `asplit` to split `ColData` by row and use `lapply` to select columns from `MainData`. We use `intersect` to get the common columns. This would give you list of dataframes.

```
lapply(asplit(ColData, 1), function(x) MainData[intersect(names(MainData), x)]) 

#[[1]]
#   XX CE.02
#1   1    NA
#2   0     0
#3   0     0
#4   1    NA
#5   0    NA
#...

#[[2]]
#   YY CE.03 CE.01
#1   0    NA    NA
#2   1     0     0
#3   0     0     0
#4   1    NA    NA
#5   0    NA    NA
#6   0     0     0
#7   1    NA    NA
#...

#[[3]]
#   ZZ CE.05
31   1    NA
#2   0     0
#3   1     0
#4   1    NA
#5   0    NA
#6   0     0
#...
```

Using `dplyr` you can do this as :

```
library(dplyr)
ColData %>%
  group_split(row_number(), .keep = FALSE) %>%
  purrr::map(~MainData %>% select(any_of(unlist(.x))))
```

Comment: Thank you for the code but somehow I am getting an error run on my dataset running first code, the second is running correctly but I also want the column name as on MainData but I am getting ColData column name. My actual dataset is big compare to the example . Error for the first code. Error in `[.data.frame`(File2, , x[!is.na(x)]) : 
  undefined columns selected

Comment: @JK1185 It means there are certain values in `ColData` which are not present in `MainData`. If the 2nd method works for you why not use that? For the first method try `lapply(asplit(ColData, 1), function(x) MainData[intersect(names(MainData), x)])`

Comment: Sorry error message is Error in [.data.frame(File2, , i[i != ""]]) : undefined columns selected

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would go about df1, df2, df3:

```
df1 <- MainData %>% select(one_of(as.character(as.vector(ColData[1]))))
df2 <- MainData %>% select(one_of(as.character(as.vector(ColData[2]))))
df3 <- MainData %>% select(one_of(as.character(as.vector(ColData[3]))))
```

Comment: Thank you but there is a slight change to your code. df1 <- MainData %>% select(one_of(as.character(as.vector(ColData[1,])))). DO you know if this can be run in 1 go for all the 3 dataset in place of running it one by one.

Answer (score 1):

A base `R` solution

```
dfs <- apply(ColData, 1L, function(i, df) df[, i[i != ""]], MainData)
df1 <- dfs[[1L]]
df2 <- dfs[[2L]]
df3 <- dfs[[3L]]
```

Comment: Thank you for the code but somehow I am getting an error run on my dataset running first code, . My actual dataset is big compare to the example. Error for the first code. Error in `[.data.frame`(File2, , x[!is.na(x)]) : 
  undefined columns selected

Comment: Sorry error message is Error in `[.data.frame`(File2, , i[i != ""]]) : 
  undefined columns selected